# Removing mixed characters in the columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to remove the character in the below columns? I got 10 columns like that

```
B15.5

e10.5

19.5K

NAN

Q2.4

NAN

T82.7

14.5

14.6P
```

I tried to use "df['column'] = df['column'].str[:-2]" but not working

"df['column'] = df['column'].str[:-2]

Comment: Pleas post your current code, input, current output and expected output.

Comment: Hi Psinaught Current code: df['column] = df['column].str[:1]. it's showing error. I need remove the character in both front and back. Example Q2.4 - i need to remove Q and 14.6P - here I need to remove p. Please suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is edited code -

```
def removeFirstLastChar(inp):
    inputStr = str(inp)
    if inputStr.lower() == 'NAN'.lower():
        return inp
    if(inputStr[0].isalpha() == True):
        inputStr = inputStr[1:]
    if(inputStr[-1].isalpha() == True):
        inputStr = inputStr[:-1]
    return float(inputStr)

print(removeFirstLastChar('Q2.4'))
print(removeFirstLastChar('14.6P'))
print(removeFirstLastChar('Q14.6P'))
print(removeFirstLastChar(float('NAN')))
```

Output -

```
2.4
14.6
14.6
nan
```

Note that this will remove only one starting or ending character from the string, if it is an alphabet -https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha.
Also, this returns a float, not a string. Change `return float(inputStr)` in function to `return inputStr` if string is required.

Comment: df is a data frame. i just made short as df. I need remove 10 columns. need to pass each value

Comment: I am geeting this error message after running the above function 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: def removeFirstLastChar(x):
    if(x[0].isalpha() == True):
        x = x[1:]
    if(x[-1].isalpha() == True):
        x = x[:-1]
    return float (x)


temp['column name'] = temp['column name'].apply(removeFirstLastChar)  After running this program.. I am getting error message 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `temp['column name']`should contain strings, above code works fine here https://www.ideone.com/X9AGnM. Can you post your whole code, including where df is being filled? Also, where is the `apply` function in `temp['column name'].apply(removeFirstLastChar)`?

Comment: def removeFirstLastChar(inputStr):
    if(inputStr[0].isalpha() == True):
        inputStr = inputStr[1:]
    if(inputStr[-1].isalpha() == True):
        inputStr = inputStr[:-1]
    return float(inputStr)

df['column name'] = df['column name'].apply(removeFirstLastChar)  # df is my pandas data frame and I am reading my data sets

Comment: Try adding `inputStr = str(inputStr)` just after `def removeFirstLastChar(inputStr):`

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
I am getting this error after adding inpuStr = str(inputStr) @psinaught

Comment: What is the data type of `df['column name']`? string or float? And are all the values in the `df['column name']` have a single character at starting or end? I see that some values in example are NAN. What are they? What needs to be done with them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190982/discussion-between-psinaught-and-jason).

Comment: data type of df['column name'] is object. Values in the columns are q12.5, 14.5, 24.5P, A12.5, 14.5, 14.5, NAN, NAN, NAN, 34.5P,23.6P--- I need to remove the first and last alphabets of the value. I don't want to change NAN or other numeric value ex 14.5

Comment: I have some problem with the coding which you taught me last week. Is it possible for you to come in private chat?